# How do I change a variable that is true to false and back to true?

Tags: python, variables, boolean

I am making a tic tac toe game and I need the image to change to "x" or an "o" depending on who's turn it is. I have a variable playerXturn that is true and the program will display a "x" when it is true. How do I change it to false so that an "o" will be displayed and then back to true for "x" to be shown again?

```
from tkinter import*
global clickable
playerXturn = True

def buttonClicked(c) : 
    if playerXturn == True :
        buttonList[c]["image"] = picX
    elif clickable[c] == "" : 
        buttonList[c]["image"] = picO


window = Tk()
window.title("Tic Tac Toe")
window.configure(background = "black")
window.geometry("400x400")

picX = PhotoImage (file = "x.gif") 
picO = PhotoImage (file = "o.gif")
picBlank = PhotoImage (file = "sw.gif") 

button1 = Button (window, text = "", image = picBlank, command = lambda: buttonClicked(0))    
button1.grid (row = 0, column = 0) 
button2 = Button (window, text = "", image = picBlank, command = lambda: buttonClicked(1))    
button2.grid (row = 0, column = 1) 
button3 = Button (window, text = "", image = picBlank, command = lambda: buttonClicked(2)) 
button3.grid (row = 0, column = 2) 
button4 = Button (window, text = "", image = picBlank, command = lambda: buttonClicked(3))  
button4.grid (row = 1, column = 0) 
button5 = Button (window, text = "", image = picBlank,  command = lambda: buttonClicked(4)) 
button5.grid (row = 1, column = 1)
button6 = Button (window, text = "", image = picBlank,  command = lambda: buttonClicked(5))  
button6.grid (row= 1, column = 2) 
button7 = Button (window, text = "", image = picBlank, command = lambda: buttonClicked(6)) 
button7.grid (row = 2, column = 0) 
button8 = Button (window, text = "", image = picBlank, command = lambda: buttonClicked(7))  
button8.grid (row = 2, column = 1) 
button9 = Button (window, text = "", image = picBlank, command = lambda: buttonClicked(8)) 
button9.grid (row = 2, column = 2) 

buttonList = [button1, button2, button3, button4, button5, button6, button7, button8, button9]
clickable = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `not` operator inverts the boolean value.

```
def buttonClicked(c):
    global playerXturn
    if playerXturn:
        buttonList[c]["image"] = picX
    elif clickable[c] == "" : 
        buttonList[c]["image"] = picO
    playerXturn = not playerXturn
```

Comment: But how would I get that to change back to true?

Comment: Just do the same thing again.

Comment: @ray Do it again. It changes `True` to `False`, and changes `False` to `True`.

Comment: It says "local variable 'playerXturn' referenced before assignment.

Comment: You weren't getting that error before you added this to the function?

Comment: I was getting it before but now I fixed it, but now it will just display the other image. I need it to display "x" "o" "x" exc. I thought of just changing it in the   if and elif statement but it says "local variable 'playerXturn' referenced before assignment.

Comment: You need to add a `global playerXturn` declaration to the function.

Answer (score -2):

You can toggle a variable with the [`not`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not) operator.

```
a_boolean = True
print a_boolean
>>> True

a_boolean = not a_boolean
print a_boolean
>>> False
```